# Get hostname from url using Trafficscript

Tags: load-balancing, scripting, zeus

I'm looking to get the hostname from a URL as it comes through Zeus and I've looked through the documentation on Trafficscript and it seems like the only option is regex.   Doe Trafficscript have a method to return url parts?

I'm looking for something kind of like [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

The reason I ask is I have the following rule

```
$url = string.lowercase(http.getPath());
if(string.contains($url, "/simple_protected_url"))
{
  http.redirect("http://mywebsite.com/");
}
```

The problem is we have our staging and development sites are not on the same domain name(`http://mywebsite.com/`) so the rule doesn't work nicely. I want to make the rule more generic so it just redirects to the root of whatever website it runs on and need a way to figure out the host to redirect to.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean? You get a HTTP (?) request and you want to extract the `Host:` header?

Comment: I think so...   Sorry if my question is not very clear.   I'm not very familiar with this type of thing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is fairly simple in TrafficScript, for example:

```
$headerHost = http.getHostHeader();

if( $headerHost == "notwhatiexpected.com") {
   # do something

}
```

`http.getHostHeader();` extracts the `Host` header from the current request.
And generally there is `http.getHeader()` to extract any header from the request.

Answer (score 0):

Check through the [Stingray Trafficscript Guide](https://support.riverbed.com/download_public.htm?filename=public/doc/stingray/trafficmanager/8.1/Stingray_8.1_TrafficScript_Guide.pdf).

I think you may be looking for `http.getRawURL()` or just `http.getHeader( "Host" )` or `http.getHostHeader()`

> Returns the HTTP Host header. This value is lowercased and has the
>   port removed. Any trailing full stop is also removed. For example if
>   the Host header is 'www.Riverbed.com:80' then http.getHostHeader()
>   returns 'www.riverbed.com'.

```
# Get the unambiguous Host header
$hostheader = http.getHostHeader();
```

Comment: They've disabled deep-linking, but I'd recommend a current version of that doc via https://support.riverbed.com/content/support/software/stingray/traffic-manager.html ;)